# Omit debug logging for specific Apex class

Tags: apex, security, debug-logs

**Scenario**

I do not want information that is processed by an Apex class called `SecureProcessor` to make it into the debug log, regardless of the level of logging enabled within Salesforce Setup.

**Question**

Is it possible to set up `SecureProcessor` class such that `VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT` information does not get logged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to get debug logs with arbitrary logging levels to omit `VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT` and other basic profiling information unless you move your code to a Managed Package.

Comment: I've created a Salesforce Idea for this: [Ability to omit an Apex class from debug logging](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EC8MQAW)